# Convert strings with an unknown number of hex strings embedded in them to strings using regex

Tags: python, regex, hex, snort

So I have a list of strings (content from Snort rules), and I am trying to convert the hex portions of them to UTF-8/ASCII, so I can send the content over netcat.

The method I have now works fine for strings with single hex characters (i.e. 3A), but breaks when there's a series of hex characters (i.e. 3A 4B 00 FF)

My current solution is:

```py
import re
import codecs

def convert_hex(match):
  string = match.group(1)
  string = string.replace(" ", "")
  decode_hex = codecs.getdecoder("hex_codec")
  try:
    result = decode_hex(string)[0]
  except:
    result = bytes.fromhex((lambda s: ("%s%s00" * (len(s)//2)) % tuple(s))(string)).decode('utf-16-le')
  return result.decode("utf-8")


strings = ['|0A|Referer|3A| res|3A|/C|3A|', 'RemoteNC Control Password|3A|', '/bbs/search.asp', 'User-Agent|3A| Mozilla/4.0 |28|compatible|3B| MSIE 5.0|3B| Windows NT 5.0|29|']

converted_strings = []

for string in strings:
    for i in range(len(string)):
        string = re.sub(r"\|(.{2})\|", convert_hex, string)
    converted_strings.append(string)
```

For the strings in `strings`, this works, but for a string like:

`|08 00 00 00 27 C7 CC 6B C2 FD 13 0E|`

it breaks.

I tried changing the regex to:

```py
re.sub(r"\|.*([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}).*\|")
```

but that only converts the last hex.

I need this solution to work for strings like `Hello|3A|World`, `|3A 00 FF|`, and `Hello|3A 00|World`

I know it's an issue with the regexp, but I'm not sure what exactly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does `|[0-9A-BFa-f]{2} ?|` work for you?

Comment: The sequence `|08 00 00 00 27 C7 CC 6B C2 FD 13 0E|` isn't a valid UTF-8 encoding, it would appear? "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 5: invalid continuation byte"

Comment: @Selcuk it appears that regexp is what I'm looking for, thank you

Comment: @Grismar sadly looks like it, I thought I'd be able to decode all the strings, but unless I can come up with some weird way to do it i dont believe ill be able to

Comment: Possibly, the content being sent to you isn't UTF-8 encoded at all, you just need to find out what the correct encoding is and pass that to the `.decode()` call.

Comment: @Grismar I think they meant a binary string, not UTF-8.

Comment: @Selcuk not sure what you mean by a binary string - all `bytes` are binary, you just need to know the encoding to represent it as a text string in a printable encoding; it doesn't appear OP needs a representation in literal binary?

Comment: @Grismar sorry I meant a byte string. Snort rules don't have to contain UTF-8 payloads as they are not HTTP only. Raw TCP/UDP rules usually contain garbage. That could pose a problem if they want to send them through `netcat`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a substring is either always hex i.e. `(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}\s)+[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}` or not hex at all between `|` symbols?

This works:

```
for string in strings:
    for i in range(len(string)):
        string = re.sub(r"(?<=\|)((?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}\s)*[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})(?=\|)", convert_hex, string)
    converted_strings.append(string)
```

(extra parentheses for a capturing group 1 - you could leave out one pair of parentheses and change your function to act on `group(0)` instead)

But it breaks on your example `|08 00 00 00 27 C7 CC 6B C2 FD 13 0E|`, as that doesn't appear to be a valid UTF-8 encoding. The resulting error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 5: invalid continuation byte
```

However, a valid UTF-8 encoded multi-byte string like `'|74 65 73 74 20 f0 9f 98 80|'` works just fine:

```
import re
import codecs

def convert_hex(match):
  string = match.group(1)
  string = string.replace(" ", "")
  decode_hex = codecs.getdecoder("hex_codec")
  try:
    result = decode_hex(string)[0]
  except:
    result = bytes.fromhex((lambda s: ("%s%s00" * (len(s)//2)) % tuple(s))(string)).decode('utf-16-le')
  return result.decode("utf-8")


strings = ['|74 65 73 74 20 f0 9f 98 80|']

converted_strings = []

for string in strings:
    for i in range(len(string)):
        string = re.sub(r"(?<=\|)((?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}\s)*[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})(?=\|)", convert_hex, string)
    converted_strings.append(string)

print(converted_strings)
```

Result:

```
['|test |']
```

If you don't really need a printable representation of the data, you could just have your function return the `bytes` object and only apply the function to matching parts - instead of constructing a new string.

Based on what @Selcuk was saying, perhaps a result with byte-strings makes more sense - this works on all three types of input:

```
import re
import codecs

def convert_hex(match):
  string = match.group(1)
  string = string.replace(b" ", b"")
  decode_hex = codecs.getdecoder("hex_codec")
  try:
    result = decode_hex(string)[0]
  except:
    result = bytes.fromhex((lambda s: ("%s%s00" * (len(s)//2)) % tuple(s))(string)).decode('utf-16-le')
  return result


strings = ['|0A|Referer|3A| res|3A|/C|3A|', '|74 65 73 74 20 f0 9f 98 80|', '|08 00 00 00 27 C7 CC 6B C2 FD 13 0E|']

converted_strings = []

for string in strings:
    string = re.sub(rb"(?<=\|)((?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}\s)*[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})(?=\|)", convert_hex, string.encode())
    converted_strings.append(string)

print(converted_strings)
```

Result:

```
[b'|\n|Referer|:| res|:|/C|:|', b'|test \xf0\x9f\x98\x80|', b"|\x08\x00\x00\x00'\xc7\xcck\xc2\xfd\x13\x0e|"]
```

No encoding issues, because no encoding is chosen. (Note that I didn't attempt to change `convert_hex` too much - there's some encoding juggling in there that you may need to look at, I just got it to work for `bytes`)

Comment: This should work beautifully for me. @Selcuk was on the money, what I actually needed were bytestrings.